# Seeing the implementation details in abstraction

Tags: java, oop, abstraction

Basic Definition of abstraction is hiding the implementation complexity of the methods and showing the functionality . Although while working with code (while I was using eclipse) there is an option of opening the implementation for the abstract methods.

For eg:-

I was trying to open the implementation for `BufferedReader` was able to see through many implementations.

So how we are hiding the complexity when we are able to see the implementation.

Where am I going wrong conceptually?

Comment: "Abstract" is an antonym of "concrete". With abstractions you represent notions and ideas, rather than the concrete way these ideas are implemented. This fits into your understanding of abstraction - you are hiding the details and you only show the interface.

Comment: The abstraction is that when you use `BufferedReader` you don't need to know how it is implemented and all that stuff.

Comment: You *chose* to open the implementations--if you don't want to see the implementations, resist the urge to open them. You said "Show me the concrete implementations."

Comment: Ya I know that we don't need to care about how it's implemented , but as I was going by the definition , I read that we are hiding the implementation complexity, So that's why I asked

Comment: They *are* hidden--you opened them. You didn't *have* to. That's the purpose of an IDE, to give you choices. Don't want to know how something is implemented? Don't open it. Nothing states "hidden to the point of being unknowable".

Comment: But I liked your point Fady that with abstractions we are representing ideas , which the reader will get after reading the functionality name and will not care about how it was implemented

Comment: Don't take hiding to mean from a security perspective i.e "You are not allowed to see this". It's more about "You don't need to see this". A laptop's casing is *hiding* the complexity of all that electronics inside. You could open it up and see all the implementation but the point is that you could just... use it.

Comment: May be I was going through security perspective and I was going by the definition too in which it's mentioned "hiding", so that's how this question struck me, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstaction does not mean hiding the implementation details from you phisically. You will still see all the implementation lines of the implenmented abstract methods unless you have your eyes. Abstraction means hiding the implementation details from the one how is intended to use the method in their code.

Assume you're writing the class that approximates the derivative of a function. Of which function? That does not matter if you think of a function as of the abstraction.
You do not care of what the function would be. You just define some basic principals of how that function should be implemented. It should take a double value and it should return a double value.

This conception hides the function implementation complexity from you as from the designer of your class. You can now proceed with implentaion your part of job. You might write the following class:

```
public abstract class DerivativeApprox {

    abstract double func(double x);

    double eps = 0.0;

    DerivativeApprox(double eps){
        this.eps = eps;
    }

    public double eval(double xPoint){
        return (func(xPoint + eps) - func(xPoint - eps)) / (2 * eps);
    }
}
```

Now anyone would be able to use your class in the following way (taking the responsibility of implementing any particular function they want to estimate the derivative)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DerivativeApprox cosDerApprox = new DerivativeApprox(0.0001) {
        @Override
        double func(double x) {
            return Math.cos(x);
        }
    };

    DerivativeApprox sinDerApprox = new DerivativeApprox(0.0001) {
        @Override
        double func(double x) {
            return Math.sin(x);
        }
    };

    System.out.println("Cos'(pi) = " + cosDerApprox.eval(Math.PI));
    System.out.println("Cos'(pi/2) = " + cosDerApprox.eval(Math.PI / 2));

    System.out.println("Sin'(pi) = " + sinDerApprox.eval(Math.PI));
    System.out.println("Sin'(pi/2) = " + sinDerApprox.eval(Math.PI / 2));

}
```

Hope this explanation will help ypu to proceed with OOP learning.

Comment: So basically you are trying to say that abstraction is how the basic structure will look like and it depends on how a designer would like to paint it. Overall your example is great(mathematical :p)

Comment: "This conception hides the function implementation complexity from you as from the designer of your class" -> Please throw some light on this point too.I didn't get it

Comment: I think you are trying to say that till the time , we don't give any concrete implementation , until then implementation complexity is hidden. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Anshul well, your last assumption is pretty much true. However this does not mean that you use abstraction because you're lazy to implement certain parts of code. You rather use abstraction to make other integrate their code into your conception.

Comment: In my example assume that both pieces of code are written by two different people. Second developer integrated their code into the conception defined by the first developer.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is correct, abstraction is hiding the implementation complexity of the methods and showing the functionality. But this is just a concept in programming. It is not a technique used to hide the implementation detail of a class or a module. You can access any predefined method or class in java library and explore them.

But advantage of the abstraction is, is gives us the possibility to use classes or methods without knowledge of their implementation details or internal structure.

Just assume you want to use `BufferedReader` class for the first time. You only need to know about the functionalities(methods) of that class. But you don't need to study about the implementation of those methods. That is hiding complexity from user. He need not to be aware of the internal complexity.

Hope this will help you....

Comment: Considering the previous discussions , I think the better line should be "He need not to be aware of the internal complexity."